# Where is CiviCRM installed?

Tags: files, filesystem

I have CiviCRM installed on my web site, and some answers on Stack Exchange tell me to change a file in CiviCRM, or to find my "civicrmroot".  I know how to access the files on my server, using FTP or SSH or my control panel's "File Explorer".  However, I don't know where to look for CiviCRM.  Where is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using CiviCRM 4.7 or higher, you can find this location by going to **Administer menu » System Settings » Directories**.  Click the blue circle with the question mark, and note the value for [civicrm.root].  See screenshot:
[image]