# Cron - Invalid key value sent

Tags: wordpress, cron

Really getting frustrated trying to get cron to work.

WP 4.7 / CiviCRM 4.7.14

using via ssh:

/usr/bin/wget 'https://hbb.org.uk/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=JohnB&pass=123&key=456'

Generates the error.

my settings.php has:

if (!defined('CIVICRM_SITE_KEY')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_SITE_KEY', '456');
}

Where the two keys are identical. There are no special characters, it's a 20 char string, I've re-entered a new string into both settings.php and the wget. Each time generates a new error log file with the msg.

When I enter the url into Chrome I get "Invalid key". Yet they're identical in the wget and settings.php.

Is there some super-sekret settings file somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Site key should be defined in `civicrm.settings.php`, not `settings.php`, which isn't necessarily bootstrapped when cron is run.

If that was mis-stated in your question (likely, since you're using WordPress), you can try to troubleshoot this by debugging.

- Find your [CiviCRM log](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) and your [CiviCRM root](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16610/where-is-civicrm-installed).
- In your CiviCRM root, find the file `CRM/Utils/System.php`.
- Find this section (around line 553):

  ```
  if ($key !== $siteKey) {
    return self::authenticateAbort(
      "ERROR: Invalid key value sent. " . $docAdd . "\n",
      $abort
    );   
  }
  ```
- Add two debugging lines so that section now looks like:

  ```
  if ($key !== $siteKey) {
    CRM_Core_Error::debug_var('key', $key);
    CRM_Core_Error::debug_var('siteKey', $siteKey);
    return self::authenticateAbort(
      "ERROR: Invalid key value sent. " . $docAdd . "\n",
      $abort
    );   
  }
  ```
- Run your cron job again, get the same error.
- Check the CiviCRM log.  At or very near the bottom of the log file, you should see lines that look like:

  ```
  $key = 456;
  $siteKey = 456;
  ```

...except I'm guessing that one of them looks slightly wrong!  Use that information to either fix this problem and/or update this question with more info.

Comment: Don't forget to remove those last two lines when you're done!

Comment: Yes, sorry, my laziness 'CIVICRM_SITE_KEY', '456' is defined in civicrm.settings.php

Comment: Weirdly error files are being saved in the domain home so I've public_html & subdomains folders .bash_history .bashrc .htaccess and then a cron.php?name=JohnB&pass=123&key=456.28 - the 28 referring to the other 27 copies as I left cron running to see what would happen :-) they all have the same content:  ERROR: Invalid key value sent. More info at:http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs

Comment: CiviCRM.5ea62a755e1d78acd0439277.log (my latest log file) doesn't appear to have those 2 lines anywhere: it's failing and generating a bucket load of error msg's but mostly around shortcodes (and the time stamps don't match the cron trigger) so something else needs looking at. :(

Comment: ok may have just spotted the deliberate error - just above the if ($key !== $siteKey) { is a line :     $siteKey = defined('CIVICRM_SITE_KEY') ? CIVICRM_SITE_KEY : NULL; will try changing NULL to the value in civicrm.setting.php

Comment: ok - changing NULL to 456 or '456' doesn't change anything - deleting the ? CIVICRM_SITE_KEY : NULL fails the whole siteKey check and it's now saying I need a siteKey of more than 7 characters.

Comment: Right - I edited the system error msg to include the two $key & $siteKey values - $siteKey was the old value (not the current civicrm.settings.php value) - anyway I've updated cron to use the old value and that seems to work. Many thanks for the pointers above @jon-g

Comment: and Civicrm is reporting cron running! Still have a "Error loading module file (). Please restore the file or disable the module." to sort out but getting there. Many thanks.

Comment: @JohnBradford Glad that my tips fixed the problem!  Of note though - the SITEKEY is never stored in the database, only in files (usually `civicrm.settings.php`).  Since you're seeing the old site key and not the current value, I'm guessing that someone stuck a SITEKEY somewhere they shouldn't have.  I would consider doing a text search for the old site key in your entire WordPress filesystem to figure out where and why.

Comment: I did a grep -r "SITE_KEY" I think it may have been a caching issue - no errant SITE_KEY def statements - cron still working.

Comment: I am having this same issue, but Like @JohnBradford, I cannot get the two lines to show up in my log.